# Returning multiple solutions with CPLEX, 'bad suffix .npool'

Tags: ampl

I've tried generating multiple solutions with cplex using

```
option solver cplexamp;
option cplex_options 'poolstub=solfile populate=1 poolintensity=4';

...

for {k in K_mach_RESOURCES} {
    solve SUB1[k];
    for {l in 1..SUB1[k].npool}{
        solution ("solfile" & l & ".sol");
        display _varname, _var;
    }
```

Gives the error

```
    Bad suffix .npool for SUB1
context:  for {l in  >>> 1..SUB1[k].npool} <<< {
Possible suffix values for SUB1.suffix:
    astatus   exitcode   message   relax
    result    sstatus    stage
```

The weird thing is that it's generating .sol files, but I don't know how to access the generated solutions! Possibly relevant info: there's multiple problems declared in the run file. Accessing Current.npool doesn't work either (in fact, it assumes Current is the latest DECLARED problem, not the latest SOLVED problem). Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the problem arose because the problem wasn't defined to be an INTEGER problem, but a LP-relaxation of an integer problem.

For some reason, CPLEX doesn't seem to support the populate method for linear programs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the "solve" command

ampl: solve;

and then you can display the results.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.